# Self-Study of Calculus Two

Tags: calculus, self-learning

I just finished self study of Calculus One and I am looking to begin Calculus Two. Is there a free platform that can help me with this?

Comment: You might want to give some idea about the contents and level of "calculus 1" and "calculus 2".

Comment: For example, this differs by country, level, and even states inside the US (I am guessing here). This is the same problem as your previous question -- provide more context, otherwise no one can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To supplement @Joe's posting,
here are the edX's [calculus courses](https://www.edx.org/learn/calculus),
the three below from MIT:

---

[image: edX_Calc]

(And there are others at that link.)
I am not sure where to draw the line between Calc 1 and Calc 2 ...

And also check out [Robert Ghrist's pages & videos on calculus](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/calculus.html):

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there are several. I know edX has some calculus courses, but I’m not sure if any are “Calculus 2” per se.

Khan Academy definitely has Calc 2:

https://www.khanacademy.org/math

Answer (score 2):

Please also see [Paul's Notes; Calc I](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjO_u6W2vXjAhUFaq0KHTvxB14QFjABegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorial.math.lamar.edu%2FClasses%2FCalcI%2FCalcI.aspx&usg=AOvVaw1qMSE1q-6I2n9McFukwsE7), and [Calc II](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjO_u6W2vXjAhUFaq0KHTvxB14QFjAAegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorial.math.lamar.edu%2FClasses%2FCalcII%2FCalcII.aspx&usg=AOvVaw3SM7E3h9Go4DB1lhUMhBPx).  Calc III is offered too.

Please see the left-most column (Table of contents) [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx) to get an overview of what Calc I, II, III offer.  There are tutorials, worked examples, exercises, and solutions to problems in each sub-topic throughout the Calculus sequence.

For more information about Paul's notes, please see the website: [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/).

See also the available courses in calculus at [MIT using OpenCourseWare (OCW)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/): assigned text, lectures, assigned exercises, etc.